# how build custom json api controller for all registered users

Tags: json, plugin-json-api

i use the [json api](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.2.-Developing-JSON-API-controllers)! from wordpress. And try to build an own json api controller, i want return all registered users with the following controller but thats not give an array with all users, suggestions

```
  public function get_users_index() {
    global $json_api;
    $users = $json_api->introspector->get_users();
    return array(
      'count' => count($users),
      'users' => array_values($users)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Look at the this JSON API , it's more recent, http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: Thanx for suggestion, but unfortunately I am to far in the proces right now with developing, suggestions for this controller?